# How to display multiple rows one after the other repeating a sequence depending on how many rows I get?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, sql

My idea is to create a Q&A section under a product profile, just like on eBay or Amazon or whatever. The idea is to send a question and then get the owner of the article to reply.

The table has these columns: **pid** (product ID), **id** (question ID), **question**, **answer**, **date** (date posted), **username**.

So if I post a question, I get the ID of the product in which I'm posting and create a question. The the owner just sends the answer to the row that matches the question.

Here's my PHP code to retrieve all the info from that table:

```
$qanda = '';
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "youknowwhat", "youknowwhat");
    mysql_select_db("youknowwhat", $link);
$qandaq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$id2' ORDER BY date", $link);
$count = mysql_num_rows($qandaq);
if($count >= 1){
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qandaq)){
        $date = $rows['date'];
        $q = $rows['question'];
        $a = $rows['answer'];
        $usrname = $rows['username'];
    }
    $qanda .= '<div id="answers" align="center">
    <table cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr align="center">
        <td width="200">' . $date . '</td>
        <td rowspan="2" width="400"><strong>' . $q . '</strong><br>' . $a . '</td>
        <td width="200">Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <td>' . $usrname . '</td>
        <td>Report</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>';
} else {
    $qanda = '<div id="answers" align="center">
    No questions for this product.
    </div>';
}
```

Now... what you see as a table in the variable `$qanda` I want to repeat it over and over again but displaying different row data but the concatenation isn't working and I can only get the last row to be displayed. I just can't seem to find out why this isn't working! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is append your divs (.=) while you're inside the while loop that mysql_fetch_array() rows.

Then you'll have a new div for each row your database returns, and you can populate it easily.

```
$qanda = '';
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qandaq)){
    $date = $rows['date'];
    $q = $rows['question'];
    $a = $rows['answer'];
    $usrname = $rows['username'];

    $qanda .= '<div id="answers" align="center">
    <table cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr align="center">
        <td width="200">' . $date . '</td>
        <td rowspan="2" width="400"><strong>' . $q . '</strong><br>' . $a . '</td>
        <td width="200">Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <td>' . $usrname . '</td>
        <td>Report</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>';


}
```

Comment: I didn't mean "for each" as in a php command, I meant it in english, that you'll have a new div for each row your database returns.

Comment: OMG I can't believe it was THAT easy... thanks so much, it worked! I'm going to mark your answer as correct when it lets me (still 4 minutes left). Happy coding!